# How to create a new SASS variable in Foundation

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

how can I create a new SASS variable in Foundation, e.g. for the top bar i have these variables:

```
// Height and margin
// $topbar-height: 45px;
// $topbar-margin-bottom: 0;
```

How could i create one for the top-margin?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the [Sass Documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variables_):

> The most straightforward way to use SassScript is to use variables. Variables begin with > dollar signs, and are set like CSS properties:
>
> ```
> $width: 5em;
> ```
>
> You can then refer to them in properties:
>
> ```
> #main {
>  width: $width;
> }
> ```

If you aren't sure how variables work, you should probably take the time to read through the official documentation on SASS; it will answer most of your basic questions. And this is an EXTREMELY basic question.

If you want to make *any* new variable, and use it elsewhere in your stylesheet:

First, you need to **set the variable**:

```
// Abstract example
$(variable name): (variable definition);
// Real-life example
$pretty-red: #ff0033;
```

Then, you need to **refer to the variable**:

```
p#highlight {
    color: $pretty-red;
}
```

Note that you can use underscores or hyphens in variable names; the Foundation practice of defining $their-variables-like-this is not mandatory, but does seem to be a fairly widespread practice.

So, to create a variable for a top margin, you would first define it:

```
$margin_amount: 40450542052rem;
```

(although I would change that margin amount if I were you!) and then refer to it, in either through the margin-top property or through the margin shorthand:

```
div { margin-top: $margin_amount; }
div { margin: $margin_amount 0 0 0;}
```